# Automation testing with activation link sent to email

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Here is the scenario: after signing up on the page, the user will receive an email with an activation link.

As a tester, instead of going to the mail and check the link to open it, I want to have automatic access to the activation link. Is there any technique on how to do this?

By the way, we are using Cypress.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Your options will depend on your context, but one route is to provide an SMTP server that also offers e.g. REST API access to the mailbox (either SaaS or something you run locally).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Cypress and wanted to test email activation flow, `MailSlurp` will serve the purpose.
You can find documentation at their [website](https://www.mailslurp.com/examples/cypress-js/) and follow the steps for setup.

General steps

`npm install --save cypress mailslurp`

And below scripts in commands.js

```js
const { MailSlurp } = require("mailslurp-client");

const apiKey = "YOUR_MAILSLURP_API_KEY";
const mailslurp = new MailSlurp({ apiKey });

Cypress.Commands.add("createInbox", () => {
  return mailslurp.createInbox();
});

Cypress.Commands.add("waitForLatestEmail", (inboxId) => {
  return mailslurp.waitForLatestEmail(inboxId);
});
```

`createInbox` will create an inbox with a unique email address and with `waitForLatestEmail` you can fetch lastest mail after activating account.